# How to decide which answer to pick if most of them contain useful information just to different aspects of the question?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

### The question in question:

[How to define function signatures partially in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658438/how-to-define-function-signatures-partially-in-haskell)

### Possible strategies

- a) Select the highest-voted answer.

  Clearly people like this best. It states that what I asked for is not supported directly, currently. Although I feel that it lacks possible workarounds.
- b) Write a new answer merging all the good ideas into one well-structured answer.

  I think this would be the most helpful for people stumbling into the question later on, but it feels like a unjust move not picking one from the people who took time to answer.
- c) Select one and then edit to include helpful bits from others' answers, even if it substantially changes the original answer.

  This is a kind of middle ground between A and B, still picking one for being helpful, and also making it more useful for future readers.
- d) Something else?

### Choice

Which strategy should I pick, and why?

Comment: If you have different aspects in your question, you probably didn't search enough before posting.

Comment: d) Upvote the answers you find useful, and don't accept any of them. Let the community decide which one should be at the top.

Comment: d) ask the original poster to include the bits you found useful from another answer for completeness and then mark their answer, therefore they have the choice of whether to include it in their answer

Comment: @dystroy Do you think it is a badly phrased question? How do you propose I should improve it?

Comment: @Yannis Well, that is the default if I don't get some decisive answers  here, I guess.

Comment: @ShadowWizard In the linked question there is an answer: "accept the one that I actually use". Would you say I should pick a workaround answer -- even if it has less upvotes?

Comment: You should always accept the answer that was most helpful *to you*. If that’s not what the community agrees on what’s the best, that’s just fine too. That’s what votes are for.

Comment: @Yannis In the long run that would just keep the question unresolved forever. So if there is an answer that really helped you, you should accept it.

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I find the whole "accepted answer" concept rather idiotic @poke, especially for questions that are a bit more than "doesn't work, halp!". But, maybe that's just me.

Comment: @Tanner That is an interesting POV. I feel like the most helpful was @Rhymoid's post since it inspired me to find a quite nice workaround that I can use right now. I also value @DominiqueDevriese's efforts, it just feels highly uncertain how long it will be before that feature gets merged into upstream and released. Will I be able to move the `accepted` mark to another answer once it gets released?

Comment: @Wizek yes, you can change accepted answer at will, no time limit on this.